SVG not rendering properly in IOS safari browser using React Native Web
I have application made on React Native Web. I have a SVG Component Which is rendered correctly in new ios and android device browser. But in some IOS ( 12, 13, 15 ) it is not rendering.
When I inspect those devices in web Inspector, I can see Svg Component Elements but it is not picking colors defined for that SVG. It seems transparent in safari browser.
it is working in android browsers and new ios version.
My current is safari 12.2
I am using SVG as component.
It seems it is not picking defs color .
this is Defs for color
 <Defs>
      <LinearGradient
        id={'b'}
        x1={187.5}
        x2={187.5}
        y1={0}
        y2={342}
        gradientUnits={'userSpaceOnUse'}
      >
        <Stop stopColor={'#003595'} />
        <Stop offset={1} stopColor={'#1A5AD7'} />
      </LinearGradient>
      <ClipPath id={'a'}>
        <Path fill={'#fff'} d={`M0 0h${width}v342H0z`} />
      </ClipPath>
    </Defs>

This is how I am accessing Id : 
<G clipPath='url(#a)'>
      <Path fill='url(#b)' d={`M0 0h${width}v342H0z`} />

I searched over internet , made code changes for svg but it did not work.
After removing Linergradient it works..any idea ?

Are id attributes with values a and b unique on the page?

YES..@Robert..id is unique in the page. I also thought same
